# Angular 2 material alpha.5-2, Angular 2 RC2, New Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

There is issue with new NG2 RC2 new forms module
If you using new form model driven approach error might occur:

> No value accessor for 'field'

I got this one when I used formControlName instead of ngControl [solution in answer]

Comment: You could add the fix you found in an answer instead in the question.

Comment: Do you mean ask question and answer it, or there is actually a section for that on stack?

Comment: No, just post an answer to your question. That's a perfectly valid thing to do. You can accept it after 2 days (AFAIR) and then it's marked as answered. I think that this makes it more obvious what the problem and what the solution is. It's IMHO rather uncommon that one seeks the solution in the question part ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you please also guide how are you using @angular/forms, I believe this need to be included in package.json. I tried adding "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.2", to my package.json and when I restore packages I receive error  No compatible version found: @angular/forms@2.0.0-rc.2

Comment: @angular/forms are version  v0.1.0, you can check it on [here](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using formControlName directive on md-input (probably others as well), error might occurre.

To fix it, change in @angular2-material/input/index.js (line: 17) from:

```
var common_1 = require('@angular/common');
```

to:

```
var common_1 = require('@angular/forms');
```

And it should work. Might happens on other material directives as well but I have checked only this one.

Also for everyone that haven't noticed **@angular/forms is version 0.1.0** not 2.0.0-rc.2

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I had this issue I forgot to add the bootstrap setting:

```
import {provideForms} from '@angular/forms'


 bootstrap(xxxAppComponent,
 [
   provideForms(),
 ]);
```